# Creating menu dropdown inside Material Navigation View with support library

Tags: android, menu, android-support-library, submenu, navigationview

As said in the title, I'm trying to create a submenu inside the standard Navigation View menu. But I want it to be expandable and material designed.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox"
        android:title="@string/inbox_string" />

    <item
        android:title="Submenu title">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuSortNewest"
                android:title="Sort by newest" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuSortRating"
                android:title="Sort by rating" />
        </menu>
    </item>


</group>
```

This way I only obtain an header, without dropdown. Any ideas on how to it?

Comment: `NavigationView` only supports a single level menu.  In order to have expandable submenus, you need to either roll your own nav drawer code or use one of the many Material Design nav drawer components on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kris-larson said in comment, NavigationView only supports a single level menu, to have an expandable submenus you need a custom navigation drawer coded, my suggestion is [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library, a flexible and easy to use drawer library for your project.

Happy coding!